# Ray Disk intersection

Tags: geometry, circles, parametric

So if I have a ray parameterized as $O + tD$ where $O$ is the origin, $D$ is the direction and $t$ is the parameter variable and a flat circular disk with a center point $P$ in 3D space and a radius $r$, how do I determine if they intersect?

Answer (score 2):

First, find the equation for the plane that contains the circular disk.  Second, find the [intersection of the line and the plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-plane_intersection).  Third, determine if the intersection point is in the right direction from the origin (the ray points only one way).  Lastly, determine if the intersection point is distance at most $r$ from the center of the disk.